# Cannot display the name parameter of product in dropdown select

Tags: angular, typescript

`enter code here`The console doesn't show any error and the fuction onsubmit() works correctly and the project is created but I can see the shop.name next to shop.id in the dropdown list. And I can only see the id. How can I change my code in order to be seen the name?

```
<form [formGroup]="priceForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<label>
    Shop:
    <select formControlName="shop_id" required>
      <option *ngFor="let shop of shops" [ngValue]="shop.id">
      {{shop.id}} {{shop.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </label>

<button type="submit" [disabled]="!priceForm.valid" >Submit</button>

</form>
```

//price-editor.component.ts

export  class  PriceEditorComponent  implements  OnInit{

getShops(): void {

```
this.shopService.getShops()

    .subscribe(shops => this.shops = shops);
```

}

priceForm = this.fb.group({

```
price: ['',  Validators.required],

shop_id: ['',Validators.required]
```

});

shops : Shop[];

myprice : Price;
  get f(){

```
return this.priceForm.controls ;
```

}
  onSubmit() {

if (this.priceForm.invalid)

{

```
 return;
```

}
    this.priceForm.get('price').value};

```
this.myprice = {price: this.f.price.value,

                shopID: this.f.shop_id.value

               };

this.priceService.create(this.myprice)
```

.subscribe(

```
 error => {console.log(this.priceForm.value);}
);
```

}

ngOnInit(){

```
this.getShops();
```

}
}

//shop.service.ts

getShop(id: number):

Observable {

const url = `${this.shopsUrl}/${id}`;

return this.http.get(url).pipe(

```
tap(_ => this.log(`fetched shop id=${id}`)),

catchError(this.handleError<Shop>(`getShop id=${id}`))
```

);
}

Comment: Where is it "not" showing shop.name, in the option label or in the selected value? What I am seeing here is that the option will show id & name, but because you have the value bound to shop.id, when an option is selected you will only see the id as the select box when selected. Is this the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: Where is this shops getting his value? you debug it and check if the property match the name:'name'

Comment: This probably means that `shop.name` is not set. I can only guess it unless you share the output of shops.

Comment: how can I change the value in order the name to be seen?should I add some else?

Comment: do a console.log of you shops variable and edit your question with the result so we can identify your error

Comment: I add the command:  .subscribe(
     //Response => {Response.
     error => {console.log(this.priceForm.value);} and I select the shop with id=12  
   and the result was :{price: "13", shop_id: "11"}

Comment: No we wanna know what are the values of your shops array

Comment: and when I go to the list of the prices, I see the new price with all the parameters, I cannot only see the name of shop in the submission form .

Comment: console.log(this.shops) please

Comment: aa sorry the shop interface is : export class Shop {
    id?: Number;
    name: string;}

Comment: The problem is not within the interface but your shops array because you are not population the names correctly , do a console.log of that array and check if in fact it has values

Comment: I did it and returns undefined

Comment: I am using the same code for displaying the list of shops and it works. Why here doesn't take it?

Comment: In  your component.ts file where you are populating the shops variable do a console log of that value

Comment: the result in tthe console is: price-editor.component.ts:28 undefined

Comment: If you can see the shop ids in the drop down but no name with that template code then `name` is not defined, has a null value, or has an empty string value on each shop instance. Check the returned json and make sure that there is an actual name value on each object in the shops array.

Comment: Guys thanks a lot, I had made a mistake with the connection in mock server. Now it is correct and it works. Thanks again.